# .NET Core model is rounding my decimal values

Tags: c#, .net-core-2.0

I have a .NET Core 2.0 app that is pulling data from an API and trying to save it to a table cog_detail (using the model CogDetail)

```
foreach (Models.Cog.CogDetail cd in cdList)
{
   _context.CogDetail.Add(cd);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

One of the values is called Lmn and shows as 2.60895M when I check the value in cd (I have a breakpoint on _context.CogDetail.Add(cd);)

But once it does the save, it is saving in the database as 3

The SQL Server table has the column as decimal(18, 0), null

My context has this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Cog.CogDetail>(entity =>
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Test_ID, e.TCode }).HasName("PK_cog_detail");

  entity.ToTable("cog_detail", "cog");

  entity.Property(e => e.Test_ID)
    .HasColumnName("test_id")
    .HasColumnType("int");

  entity.Property(e => e.TCode)
    .HasColumnName("tcode")
    .HasColumnType("varchar(10)");

  entity.Property(e => e.Lmn)
    .HasColumnName("lmn")
    .HasColumnType("decimal(18, 0)");

});
```

Any ideas on why it is rounding up instead of staying as 2.60895?

Comment: Doesn't `decimal(18, 0)` mean "18 digits total, with none to the right of the decimal point"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `18,0` means you have a total of 18 digit decimal, and 0 numbers to the right of the decimal point. So that's basically an 18 digit whole number. Fix that first and see what happens.

Comment: You're absolutely right.. stunned I missed that.  Going to test now

Comment: That did the trick.. the amount of hours I've spent staring in the wrong place to fix this!

Thanks all - I'll mark this complete

Comment: @Flydog57 You should add this as an answer, otherwise we should just close this as a typo.

Comment: @DavidG It should be closed as a typo anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by Flydog57 and Train in the comments.

Column type should have been 18, 6 - not 18, 0 as that had no numbers to the right of the decimal point

Comment: Too late, oh well. I'm in Dallas. Tje temperature is dropping 40 deg F overnight. I could use the hat